# Testing Backbone Model with Jasmine and Sinon - Object #<Object> has no method 'spy'

Tags: testing, backbone.js, jasmine, sinon

I am trying to learn how to use Jasmine and Sinon for testing a Backbone application, and I was following [this tutorial](http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/25/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon-2.html). Nevertheless, I ran into a problem that I don't know how to solve.

Most likely the solution is simple, but I need some guidance ...

In my project.spec.js file this is the code that is giving the problem:

```
it("should not save when name is empty", function() {
    var eventSpy = sinon.spy();
    this.project.bind("error", eventSpy);
    this.project.save({"name": ""});
    expect(this.eventSpy.calledOnce).toBeTruthy();
    expect(this.eventSpy.calledWith(
      this.project, 
      "cannot have an empty name"
    )).toBeTruthy();
});
```

And this is the specific error that can be seen in the browser:

```
Failing 1 spec
7 specs | 1 failing
Project model should not save when name is empty.
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'spy'
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'spy'
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8888/__spec__/models/project.spec.js:53:26)
    at jasmine.Block.execute (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:1024:15)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:2025:31)
    at jasmine.Queue.start (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:1978:8)
    at jasmine.Spec.execute (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:2305:14)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:2025:31)
    at onComplete (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:2021:18)
    at jasmine.Suite.finish (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:2407:5)
    at null.onComplete (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:2451:10)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost:8888/__JASMINE_ROOT__/jasmine.js:2035:14)
```

In addition to the sinon.js library, I have installed the jasmine-sinon.js library (both are in the vendor/assets/javascripts folder and are included in the application.js file).

Thank you,
Alexandra

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you've posted here, are you sure it's loading sinon properly? What if you remove all lines in the test except the first (`var eventSpy = sinon.spy()`) ?

Comment: The same error is present when I remove all lines from the test except for the one you mention. If I delete the line '//= require sinon.js' from application.js, the error becomes 'ReferenceError: sinon is not defined'. This means that sinon.js is loaded when '//= require sinon.js' is mentioned - at least the sinon object is accessible. Maybe I am not referencing this object properly?

Comment: No, the line itself is fine. Since it gives a ref error when you remove sinon.js that means that in the test, `sinon` is defined but for some reason it doesn't have the `spy` method. Is it possible that you assigned something to `sinon` in an earlier test? Something like: `sinon = ...`?

Comment: No, I did not ... that is the only place sinon is referenced. Maybe I need to look at the sinon.js code to see what happens there.

Comment: If you're using firebug or some other js debugging tool, you could try `console.log(sinon);` and then see what you get.

Comment: Using console.log, I can see that sinon is an object, which has "spy" as one of its properties. It does not seem to have a "spy" function.

Comment: That's pretty strange... I'm not really sure what's going on.

Comment: Actually you shouldn't be putting test-specific javascript files into application.js. They should go into spec/javascripts/spec.js. That might explain it.

Comment: In spec.js, would I need to use the same format to include the javascript libraries? I am trying to find the right path to reference in the //=require statement, but for the moment the sinon library is not properly included (//= require /vendor/assets/javascripts/sinon.js).

Comment: You shouldn't actually have to include any path, just `require sinon` and `require jasmine-sinon`. Sprockets should take care of figuring out the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to post this as an answer, based on the comment thread above. We've narrowed down the problem to the line where `sinon.spy()` is called, so it's not specific to this test but to how sinon is being loaded.

I suspect the problem is that you're including sinon and jasmine-sinon in application.js, when they should really go in spec/javascripts/spec.js (in the same format). Try changing that and see if anything changes.

UPDATE:

Based on the comment thread below, it seems the code is getting to the `this.project.save(...)` line but the validations aren't working: I know this because if you're getting a POST error in the console, it means that backbone actually made the request (which it should not have because the name is empty). So you should go back and check the code you are actually testing.

Comment: After creating the spec.js file that contains the lines `//= require application
//= require_tree .
//= require jasmine-sinon
//= require sinon`, moving the sinon.js and jasmine-sinon.js files in the helpers folder under spec/javascripts, the object printed out when I tried console.log(sinon) contained the spy function. Nevertheless, I still get an error: `TypeError: sinon.spy is undefined. var _invoke = sinon.spy.invoke;` Any additional thoughts? Btw, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The order in spec.js should be: require_tree ./, require sinon, require jasmine-sinon, require application (at least that's what it is in my file). Also you can leave sinon and jasmine-sinon where you had them in the vendor/assets/javascripts folder, that's no problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the order did not fix the error .. There is also a POST error. The response is `File not found: /projects`.

Comment: Did you add the other lines back after `eventSpy = sinon.spy`? If so then the POST error is from the `this.project.save(...)` line. Do you have any beforeEach block for this test? If so please include it.

Comment: The beforeEach statement is `beforeEach(function() {
      var projects = {
        url: "/projects"
      };
      this.project.collection = projects;
    });` With or without this block, I get the same error.

Comment: I added an update to my answer. If you're seeing a POST error it's because backbone is actually trying to send the data to the server, which means your validation is **not** working. I'm still not sure about what the sinon.spy error is, but I think your problem is in your actual code for the project model.

Comment: I managed to fix an error that I did not notice earlier (referencing eventSpy with this.eventSpy was a problem). This helped me get a bit further with the code, but the sinon.spy error is still there ... Nevertheless, shioyama helped me with my initial question. Hopefully, I'll be able to solve the rest as well.

Comment: Thanks, sorry that I couldn't get the full answer. It's hard to answer questions where the environment plays a major factor, because I don't know all the settings, etc.

Comment: I reached the conclusion that the error is not relevant, since the tests I was working on all look fine now. Hopefully this is the case :). Thank you so much for your help, again! You were awesome!

Answer (score 6):

I faced this problem when I downloaded sinon.js file from GitHub (without Sinon folder). I solved the problem by downloading the library from http://sinonjs.org/

Comment: Confirming this solved the issue for me as well - thanks, saved me a headache

Comment: I had a similar problem (bower, amd, mocha, sinon) with sinon.stub(myObject, aMethod), which emerged when I switched from a downloaded file (from http://sinonjs.org) to a bower installed package. I tried to require, shim the dependencies for stub.js (spy.js and behavior.js) but gave up. Restored the downloaded sinon-1.9.0.js and it all worked again. I'm sure I "required" the modules incorrectly - my exact problem was that the stub method returned a spy it seemed and not a stub (I needed to call mystub.returns(true) which threw no method returns on proxy). Does this make sense at all?

Comment: Ehhm just realized I was missing call.js included this in the required modules and now it works hunky dory.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I had a similar issue today with this when going through this tutorial http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/25/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon-2.html.  It looks like Backbone made a change and it calls the 'invalid' event when invalid model data is provided, not 'error'.

If you run into this error try changing:

```
it("should not save when name is empty", function() {
    ...
    this.project.bind("error", eventSpy);
    ...
});
```

To:

```
it("should not save when name is empty", function() {
    ...        
    this.project.bind("invalid", eventSpy);
    ...
});
```

This resolved the issue for me.